# Combine "Exclude" Query in functions.php

Tags: query, exclude

I was wonder if I can combine these two pieces of code together?

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
      $query->set( 'cat', '-103' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );

function exclude_feed( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_feed ) {
       $query->set( 'cat', '-103' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_feed' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put both `if` statements with `||` (or) in the one callback function:

```
function wpse_283481_exclude_posts( $query ) {
    if ( ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) || $query->is_feed() ) { 
        $query->set( 'cat', '-103' ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_283481_exclude_posts' );
```